# Mercurial hgignore/subinclude not working for directories

Tags: mercurial

This .hgignore doesn't seem to be working for me. The glob files are ignored but not the things specified in the subincludes:

```
subinclude:SDK.Workspace/.hgignore

subinclude:SDK.Workspace/Application/.hgignore

syntax: glob

*.pyc
*.o
*.d
```

Is it not supported in this version? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

```
$ hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.0.1)
```

---

```
Directory: ~/Development/CCL/SDK.Workspace
$ cat .hgignore 
Application.BSP
Hardware
webtalk
SDK.log
RemoteSystemsTempFiles
.metadata
Directory: ~/Development/CCL/SDK.Workspace
$ hg status Hardware
? Hardware/.project
? Hardware/fmm_c5_mb.bit
? Hardware/fmm_c5_mb_bd.bmm
? Hardware/ps7_init.c
? Hardware/ps7_init.h
? Hardware/ps7_init.html
? Hardware/ps7_init.tcl
? Hardware/system.hdf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version is simply not recent enough.  The [`subinclude` feature was introduced in Mercurial v3.5](https://lwn.net/Articles/653506/).